# connection refuse on neo4j-silex

Tags: php, neo4j

I'm using neo4j, 3.3.4, is newly installed with the default configuration, I can access from my browser, when I try to access from my application silex returns: **cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 7474: Connection refused**. I have this in my composer file:

```
"graphaware/neo4j-php-client": "^4.8",
"kbrabrand/silex-neo4j": "^2.0"
```

In the AppServiceProvider file

```
$app->register(new Neo4jServiceProvider(), array(
    'neo4j.transport' => 'localhost', // Hostname as string, or Everyman\Neo4j\Transport object
    'neo4j.port'      => 7474,        // Port number, ignored if transport is not a string
));
```

}

This is the Controller code:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:1234567@localhost:7474')// Example for HTTP connection configuration (port is optional)
            ->build();
        $query = 'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n';
        $result = $client->run($query);
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Doesn't your neo4j require a password for the connection ?

Comment: Yes, the user is **neo4j** and the password **1234567**, that's why I specify, **http://neo4j:1234567@localhost:7474**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot a detail that is crucial, my php code was running from a Docker container, therefore, the address to consume the Neo4j server could not be **localhost**, it had to be, **172.17.0.1**, now it works well, I leave this here for someone else to use it. :)

Finally I created a docker file to put the php container and the Neo4j container, here is the docker file.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  neo4j:
      image: neo4j:3.3.4
      ports:
        - "7474:7474"
        - "7687:7687"
  app:
    image: silex:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    links:
      - neo4j
    ports:
      - "7018:80"
```

This way in the controller I can call the Neo4j in the following way (the user I use is: **neo4j** and the password: **1234567**):

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
                ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:1234567@neo4j:7687')
                ->build();
            $query = "MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 25";
            $result = $client->run($query);
```